# GCC fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory

Tags: mpi

When I try to execute code by using this command:

```
gcc ASD.c -o ASD.out*
```

I get this:

```
ASD.c:2:10: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <mpi.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Any help to fix this, please?

Comment: Please add details to your question: what is `ASD.c`, do you have any guides about its compilation? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Install some of the packages shown by `dpkg -S /usr/include/mpi.h`

Answer (score 4):

This error message means that your system misses header file named [`mpi.h`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=mpi.h).

Depending on your use-case you need to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-generic libmpich-dev libopenmpi-dev
```

Comment: OP's system may have the `mpi.h` header, but the compile line does not have the `-Iwhatever` include option with the MPI directories.

Answer (score 2):

For compiling MPI codes you should use `mpicc` as the compiler. This is a script* around gcc (or whatever compiler you have) that sets the proper include and library paths.

If `mpicc` is an unknown command on your system, see the other answer for the missing packages.

*with OpenMPI it's actually a small executable.